# Set ViewBag property in the constructor of a ASP.NET MVC Core controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My theme has some sort of breadcrumb. The controller is always the category. To avoid repeat myself, I want to set it in the constructor of the controller for all actions like this:

```
class MyController:Controller{
    public MyController() {
        ViewBag.BreadcrumbCategory = "MyCategory";
    }
}
```

When I access `ViewBag.BreadcrumbCategory` in the layout-view, its null. In a Action it works:

```
class MyController:Controller{
    public IActionResult DoSomething() {
        ViewBag.BreadcrumbCategory = "MyCategory";
    }
}
```

I'm wondering that setting a ViewBag property is not possible in a constructor? It would be annoying and no good practice to have a function called on every action which do this work. In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930797/declare-viewbag-on-controller) using the constructor was an accepted answear, but as I said this doesn't work, at least for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: You should use an action filter.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is an [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1422#issuecomment-59997202) about it and it's stated that this is by design. The answer you linked is about ASP.NET MVC3, the old legacy ASP.NET stack.

ASP.NET Core is written from scratch and uses different concepts, designed for both portability (multiple platforms) as well as for performance and modern practices like built-in support for Dependency Injection.

The last one makes it impossible to set `ViewBag` in the constructor, because certain properties of the `Constructor` base class must be injected via Property Injection as you may have noticed that you don't have to pass these dependencies in your derived controllers.

This means, when the `Controller`'s constructor is called, the properties for `HttpContext`, `ControllerContext` etc. are not set. They are only set **after** the constructor is called and there is a valid instance/reference to this object.

And as pointed in the GitHub issues, it won't be fixed because this is by design.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.0.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs#L91), ViewBag has a dependency on `ViewData` and `ViewData` is populated after the controller is initialized. If you call `ViewBag.Something = "something"`, then you it will create a new instance of the `DynamicViewData` class, which will be replaced by the one after the constructor gets initialized.

As @SLaks pointed out, you can use an action filter which you configure per controller.

The following example assumes that you **always** derive your controllers from `Controller` base class.

```cs
public class BreadCrumbAttribute : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public BreadCrumbAttribute(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);

        var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
        if (controller != null) 
        {
            controller.ViewBag.BreadcrumbCategory = _name;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to decorate your controller with it.

```cs
[BreadCrumb("MyCategory")]
class MyController:Controller
{
}
```

Comment: With the latest version of dotnetcore, `IActionFilter` requires both `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted` to be implemented. Neither of these are async functions, so the await causes an error state, and the base item is type object, so it doesn't have an `OnActionExecuting` function to call.

Comment: @Grungondola: ASP.NET Core also has async action filters: with the `IAsyncActionFilter` interface, but the code above does action nothing async so sync one works fine. Just removed the await keyword, not sure how it got in there

Answer (score 18):

I have the same issue and solve it overriding the `OnActionExecuted` method of the controller:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        ViewBag.Module = "Production";
    }
```

Comment: This answer is for MVC Core

Comment: This is the best answer. Worked on .NET 7

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better way to do this for .NET Core 3.x, use the ResultFilterAttribute:

Create your own custom filter attribute that inherits from ResultFilterAttribute as shown below:

```
   public class PopulateViewBagAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
    {


        public PopulateViewBagAttribute()
        {
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            //   context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add(_name, new string[] { _value });
            (context.Controller as MyController).SetViewBagItems();
            base.OnResultExecuting(context);
        }
    }
```

You'll need to implement the method SetViewBagItems to populate your ViewBag

public void SetViewBagItems()
        {
                ViewBag.Orders = Orders;
        }

Then Decorate your Controller class with the new attribute:

```
  [PopulateViewBag]
  public class ShippingManifestController : Controller
```

That's all there is to it!  If you are populating ViewBags all over the place from your constructor, then you may consider creating a controller base class with the abstract method SetViewBagItems.  Then you only need one ResultFilterAttribute class to do all the work.