# ASP.Net Core lifecycle of ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-core

I am converting a legacy ASP.Net MVC website to Core, and I used to have all controllers inherit from a BaseController class which was overriding `Initialize` and setting some properties on the `ViewBag`.  There seems to be no `Initialize` method now, so I'm doing that through the constructor. However, by the time I get to the Action method, it seems the `ViewBag` has been reset.

The code is basically like this:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected BaseController()
    {
        ViewBag.Hello = "hello";
    }
}

public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var hello = ViewBag.Hello;
        // but hello is null

        return View();
    }
}
```

Should I be overriding a different method rather than going through the constructor? Where is `ViewBag` getting reset and what is a better way to work around that?

Comment: "The data you put in the ViewBag/ViewData is only available during the life-cycle of the request within which you populated it" Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186674/viewbag-viewdata-lifecycle/9186855#9186855) . Besides, you can look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676924/what-is-the-right-time-for-viewdata-viewbag-session-tempdata) to know more.

Comment: But in my example it's the same request. However, the ViewBag is being reset within the lifecycle of a single request.

Comment: How do you excute the  MyController  ?

Comment: That's an MVC web page, so you're just hitting a url in your browser, e.g. localhost:8083/My/Index in this example

Comment: When I test your code , `MyController : BaseController` I will get the Error: AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints . Do you have ?

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to assist me, but you have routing issues and this question isn't the right place to resolve those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override [OnActionExecuting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting?view=aspnetcore-8.0) method :

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        //protected BaseController()
        //{
        //    ViewBag.Hello = "hello";
        //}
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            ViewBag.Hello = "hello";
           
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: @Savage  '' it impossible to set ViewBag in the constructor"  Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330391/set-viewbag-property-in-the-constructor-of-a-asp-net-mvc-core-controller) .